# Sending SQL alert when WITNESS is disconnected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job, database-mirroring

I'm looking for some help setting an alert to fire when the 'mirroring_witness_state_desc' in the following query returns a 'DISCONNECTED' value.  We've had incidents where the WITNESS server will randomly drop all connections to it's mirrored databases and I'd like to catch when this is happening.

The query I'm using to gather this information is:

```
SELECT d.name, d.database_id, m.mirroring_role_desc,
               m.mirroring_state_desc, m.mirroring_safety_level_desc, 
               m.mirroring_partner_name, m.mirroring_partner_instance,
               m.mirroring_witness_name, m.mirroring_witness_state_desc
FROM   sys.database_mirroring m JOIN sys.databases d
ON     m.database_id = d.database_id
WHERE  mirroring_state_desc IS NOT NULL
```

I'd like to have this set as a job running every few hours throughout the day.

Thanks very much for any pointers!

Comment: Probably need to use DBMail for this. An alternative is to set up a SQL Agent Alert for a WMI query, as mirroring will send a WMI alert if there was a state change. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/use-warning-thresholds-and-alerts-on-mirroring-performance-metrics-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#UseAlerts and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-wmi-event-alert?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks very much CharlieFace, I'll look at those links now!